# Updating Custom Portal Settings in DNN 7.3 +

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I am taking over and modernizing a model from another developer.

They had the following line in the settings.ascx page of the Module settings:

```
 DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals.PortalSettings.UpdatePortalSetting(this.PortalId, "setting_name", tx_emailfrom.Text);
```

Which throws the following warning

> Warning       'PortalSettings.UpdatePortalSetting(int, string, string)' is obsolete: 'Deprecated in DNN 5.0. Replaced by DataProvider.UpdatePortalSetting(Integer, String, String)'

So I changed the line to:

```
DotNetNuke.Data.DataProvider.UpdatePortalSetting( this.PortalId, "setting_name", tx_emailfrom.Text, UserId, "en-US");
```

As suggested but now I get the following error:

> Error CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'DataProvider.UpdatePortalSetting(int, string,
>   string, int, string)'

What is the most up to date way to update the portal settings for DNN 7.3 and above.  I can get the portal settings, just having trouble updating them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is how I solved it

One note, this answer is for "custom" portal settings.  So VDWWD's solution works for all existing portal settings of the portal object.

I fixed this my adding .Instance() to the following line:

```
 DataProvider.UpdatePortalSetting( this.PortalId, "bulletin_sendemail_from", this.tx_emailfrom.Text, UserId, "en-US");
```

is changed to

```
 DataProvider.Instance().UpdatePortalSetting( this.PortalId, "bulletin_sendemail_from", this.tx_emailfrom.Text, UserId, "en-US");
```

And now it works

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

```
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Portals;

//get the current portal settings
PortalInfo portalInfo = PortalController.Instance.GetPortal(PortalId);

//overwrite a specific setting
portalInfo.PortalName = "My New Portal Name";

//save the new portal settings
PortalController portalController = new PortalController();
portalController.UpdatePortalInfo(portalInfo);
```

You may need to clear the cache for the new settings to take effect.

```
DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.DataCache.ClearPortalCache(PortalId, false);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but the setting I am talking about is a "custom" setting and is not a property of the PortalObject.